# What's the difference for Future and future?

Tags: scala

Next code are both Ok, why we need the new function future? It seems future just has following signture, anything I miss E.g. for some situation we can just use one of them?

```
def future[T](body: =>T)(implicit execctx: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = Future[T](body)
```

Following is the test code:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

Future {
  println("1")
}

future {
  println("2")
}

Thread.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scala.concurrent.future` was [deprecated](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.concurrent.package@future[T](body:=>T)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]) in 2.11.0 and will be removed in a future version of Scala, so the answer is you don't need both, and don't use `future`.